# How can I extract complete value in _id field from mongodb using groovy?

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I am trying to pull complete value in _id column against a particular record but I am just getting the string part.What am I doing wrong?

```
Document result = collection.find(eq("EmployeeOID",1111111)).first();
if(result !=null){
String ID =result.get("_id");   
ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(result.get("_id"));
vars.put('myID', objectId as String);
log.info (vars.get('myID'))
return objectId; 
}
return "Employee not found";
```

Expected result: 
 ObjectId("5dc2cbc6da7bec484cc0be9e")

What I Am getting through my above code:
 5dc2cbc6da7bec484cc0be9e

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is going for simple [string concatenation](https://dzone.com/articles/concatenate-strings-in-groovy) using i.e. [GStringTemplateEngine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_gstringtemplateengine), something like:

```
String completeValue = "ObjectId(\"$ID\")"
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance I actually thought of this way already but was wondering if there is some genuine way of doing the same ?